# Use the first and last day of Data Studio Date Range in calculation

Tags: looker-studio

**Example Table:**

```
Date, CustomerID
2020-01-01,a
2020-01-01,b
2020-01-01,c
2020-01-02,a
[...]
2020-01-31,a
2020-01-31,b
2020-01-31,c
2020-01-31,d
2020-02-01,a
2020-02-01,b
[...]
```

Let's say I have a date range set on 2020-01-01 - 2020-01-31.

Id like to calculate the difference between:

```
(count_distinct(CustomerId) with filter Date=2020-01-01) - (count_distinct(CustomerId) with filter Date=2020-01-31) and get the result 1.
```

I've tried `MAX(Date)` and `MIN(Date)`, however I can't find a way to use that as a filter.

When connecting to big query i can use `@DS_START_DATE`, but I'd like to use this inside of data studio.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can accomplish this with creating three formula fields?

MIN(Date), MAX(Date) and then another formula field for the difference between the two.

Not sure if that would work for your data set but it came to mind.

Comment: Do you mean: StartDate : MIN(Date) ; EndDate : MAX(Date) ; And then DATE_DIFF ? That casts Invalid formula :( But great idea.